# Get all lists and sites using a given site column in sharepoint 2007 using powershell

Tags: 2007, list, sharepoint-foundation, spfield

In other words, is there a SPField.ListsFieldUsedIn() equivalent in SharePoint 2007?
Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.listsfieldusedin.aspx

Comment: I checked both SPField and SPList class members. Nothing in either have any property or method that will give me a connection between the two. Please help. I need to findout whether a given Site Column is already added to the List.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how it's done in SharePoint 2010:

```
public ICollection<SPFieldTemplateUsage> ListsFieldUsedIn()
{
    List<SPFieldTemplateUsage> list = new List<SPFieldTemplateUsage>();
    using (SPSqlCommand command = new SPSqlCommand())
    {
        using (SqlDataReader reader = this.GetSqlDataForPushdown(command))
        {
            if (reader != null)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    SPFieldTemplateUsage item = new SPFieldTemplateUsage();
                    item.WebID = (Guid) reader[0];
                    item.ListID = (Guid) reader[1];
                    list.Add(item);
                }
                reader.Close();
            }
            return list;
        }
    }
}

private SqlDataReader GetSqlDataForPushdown(SPSqlCommand cmd)
{
    SPSite site = this.Fields.Web.Site;
    SqlSession sqlSession = site.SqlSession;
    cmd.SetStoredProcedure("proc_ListsUsingFieldTemplate");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SiteId", site.ID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FieldId", this.Id.ToByteArray());
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaseTypes", SPBaseFieldId.BaseTypesFromFieldId(this.Id));
    return sqlSession.ExecuteReader((SqlCommand) cmd);
}
```

I don't have a SharePoint 2007 VM handy to see if the stored proc exists.

The alternative is to loop through all the lists in the site collection and check the Fields collection. It won't be fast but it'll do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the code Rob. If you could post the loop, I could mark it as answer. In fact, that is exactly what I ended up doing. I had to loop through all the lists in the site collection and use the List.Fields() method.